# Conditionally replace values over a dataset R

Tags: r, replace, conditional-formatting

**Background**

In this data set, 1 corresponds to a positive (yes) response and 2 corresponds with a negative (no) response. The dataset has been truncated from a larger data set.

```
data <- structure(list(col1 = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, NA), 
                       col2 = c(2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1), 
                       col3 = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1), 
                       col4 = c(2, 2, 2, NA, 1, 2, NA), 
                       col5 = c(2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                       col6 = c(2, 1, 2, NA, 1, 1, 2), 
                       col7 = c(2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1), 
                       col8 = c(2, 2, 2, NA, 2, 2, 1), 
                       col9 = c(2, 2, 2, NA, 2, 2, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                       "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The data set produces the following results using `tibble()`.

```
# A tibble: 6 x 9
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8  col9
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     1     2     2     2     2     2     2
2     2     2     1     2     2     1     2     2     2
3     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
4     1     1     1     NA    1     NA    1     NA    NA
5     1     1     1     1     1     1     2     2     2
6     2     2     2     2     1     1     2     2     2
7     NA    1     1     NA    1     2     1     1     1
```

**My Question**

My question is that for all observation that have at least one **YES (1) response** and no **NO (2) responses**, recode any missing values to 2. So, in this case, observations 4 would be altered but not 7 as 7 would fit the condition set. This would produce the desired.

```
# A tibble: 6 x 9
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8  col9
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     1     2     2     2     2     2     2
2     2     2     1     2     2     1     2     2     2
3     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
4     1     1     1     2     1     2     1     2     2
5     1     1     1     1     1     1     2     2     2
6     2     2     2     2     1     1     2     2     2
7     NA    1     1     NA    1     2     1     1     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work:

```
data[t(apply(data, 1, function(x) (1 %in% x) & !(2 %in% x) & is.na(x)))] <- 2
data
# A tibble: 7 × 9
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8  col9
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     1     2     2     2     2     2     2
2     2     2     1     2     2     1     2     2     2
3     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
4     1     1     1     2     1     2     1     2     2
5     1     1     1     1     1     1     2     2     2
6     2     2     2     2     1     1     2     2     2
7    NA     1     1    NA     1     2     1     1    NA
```

Comment: Thank you so much! If I could ask, how do I interpret the %in% operator? Would my interpretation be correct in saying if a column contains 1 and does not contain 2?

Comment: @Harambe, yes your interpretation is accurate

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it can work :

```
apply(data, 1, function(row){
  if (1 %in% row && !2 %in% row){ifelse(is.na(row), 2, row)}
  else{row}
})
```